# Equivalent of Java algorithm in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code for decryption of DES encrypted encoded message in `Java`.

```
    try 
    {
        byte[] key = new String(keyString).getBytes();
        byte[] enc = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedMessage);
        SecretKey generateSecret = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(key));
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        cipher.init(2, generateSecret);
        String dec = new String(cipher.doFinal(enc));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
    }
```

I want to port this into C#. Though, I am not sure how to handle `SecretKey generateSecret = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(key));` Here is the `C#` code I am using for DES decryption:

```
    byte[] enc = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedMessage);
    byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);

    using (DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        des.Key = key;
        ICryptoTransform desDecrypt = des.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] result = desDecrypt.TransformFinalBlock(enc, 0, enc.Length);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
    }
```

The value of `keyString` I have is more than 30 bytes and `des.Key` needs 8 bytes. Upon reading the documentation for `new DESKeySpec()` I have found out that it takes the first 8 bytes. So, I took the 8 bytes and used it as key for `des.Key` and the code crashes complaining about padding. So, I have realized this is not the way to handle this. I am not sure how to handle this. Your info is appreciated.

Comment: I guess, you need to specify [PaddingMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode?view=net-8.0). `des.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;`

Comment: @SrejonKhan Nope that does not help. I even went with `PaddingMode.None` and even though this None mode worked, it resulted in gibberish decrypted message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Java code, no mode is specified in `Cipher.getInstance("DES")`, so that the provider-dependent default value is used, which in the case of the SunJCE provider is ECB.
The C# code, on the other hand, uses the CBC mode by default, which must therefore be changed to ECB for compatibility with the Java code.
Padding is not a problem here, as the SunJCE provider and the C# side use PKCS#7 by default (which is called PKCS#5 in the Java world for historical reasons).

The following C# code works:

```cs
string keyString = "01234567890123456789012345678901";
string encryptedMessage = "gGSWHv6xiA3s2sr4aZzyA+g4fSGvnJ8NfxUiO6HMIazO+wJNy6dbdZK7KE0JcbyI";

byte[] enc = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedMessage);
byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString)[0..8]; // get the first 8 bytes

using (DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    des.Key = key;
    des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; // choose ECB mode
    ICryptoTransform desDecrypt = des.CreateDecryptor();
    byte[] result = desDecrypt.TransformFinalBlock(enc, 0, enc.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result)); // The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
}
```

where the test data has been chosen so that the Java code decrypts the ciphertext `encryptedMessage` with the key `keyString`.

---

Note that it is advisable to specify the mode and padding explicitly on the Java side (e.g. `Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")`) in order to remain unaffected by the provider-dependent default.
Likewise, the character set should be specified in the Java code when encoding and decoding (e.g.   `new String(cipher.doFinal(enc), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`), as otherwise the platform-dependent default is used.
Be aware that DES and ECB are insecure (DES has been deprecated for about 20 years, its successor is AES; more secure than ECB is CBC or even better authenticated encryption such as GCM).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and mostly the explanation. Much appreciated.